# UITextField can't edit,focus

Tags: ios, uitextfield, edit, uiwindow

```
//
//  SignStepRemindView.m
//  LTPMS
//
//  Created by longdw on 16/7/14.
//  Copyright © 2016年 longdw. All rights reserved.
//

#define kPadding 10

#import "SignStepRemindView.h"
#import "SignStepRemindCell.h"
#import "UITableViewCell+AutoHeightForCell.h"
#import "NSString+Frame.h"

@interface SignStepRemindView() <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *backIv;

@property(nonatomic, weak) UIView *contentView;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIView *remindContentView;

@property(nonatomic, weak) UIButton *leftBtn;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIButton *rightBtn;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UILabel *titleLabel;

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger step;

@property(nonatomic, weak) UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation SignStepRemindView

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.backgroundColor = kGlobalBgColor;

        [self addViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addViews
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.titleLabel = titleLabel;
    titleLabel.text = @"select step";
    titleLabel.textColor = kNavColor;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    [self addSubview:titleLabel];

    WEAKSELF
    [titleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.left.equalTo(weakSelf).offset(kPadding);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(30);
    }];

    UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:bottomView];
    [bottomView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.bottom.equalTo(weakSelf).offset(-kPadding * 0.5);
        make.left.equalTo(weakSelf);
        make.right.equalTo(weakSelf).offset(-kPadding);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(40);
    }];

    UIButton *rightBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.rightBtn = rightBtn;
    rightBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [rightBtn setTitleColor:kNavColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtn setTitle:@"next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(next) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bottomView addSubview:rightBtn];
    [rightBtn mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.equalTo(bottomView);
        make.height.equalTo(bottomView);
        make.centerY.equalTo(bottomView.mas_centerY);
        make.width.mas_equalTo(60);
    }];

    UIButton *leftBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.leftBtn = leftBtn;
    leftBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [leftBtn setTitleColor:kNavColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftBtn setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bottomView addSubview:leftBtn];
    [leftBtn mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.equalTo(rightBtn.mas_left).offset(-kPadding);
        make.height.equalTo(bottomView);
        make.centerY.equalTo(bottomView.mas_centerY);
        make.width.mas_equalTo(60);
    }];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView = scrollView;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.mas_bottom).offset(kPadding);
        make.bottom.equalTo(bottomView.mas_top);
        make.left.equalTo(weakSelf).offset(kPadding);
        make.right.equalTo(weakSelf).offset(-kPadding);
    }];

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.contentView = contentView;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:contentView];
    [contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(scrollView);
        make.height.equalTo(scrollView);
    }];

    //first
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tableView = tableView;
//    tableView.delegate = self;
//    tableView.dataSource = self;

    UIView *view = [UIView new];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tableView setTableFooterView:view];
    [contentView addSubview:tableView];
    [tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.bottom.equalTo(contentView);
        make.width.equalTo(weakSelf.scrollView);
    }];

    //second
    UIScrollView *remindScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [contentView addSubview:remindScrollView];
    [remindScrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(tableView.mas_right);
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(contentView);
        make.width.equalTo(weakSelf.scrollView);
    }];

    UIView *remindContentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.remindContentView = remindContentView;
    [remindScrollView addSubview:remindContentView];
    [remindContentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(remindScrollView);
        make.width.equalTo(remindScrollView);
    }];

    [contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.equalTo(remindScrollView.mas_right);
    }];

    [self addRemindView];
}

- (void)addRemindView
{
    UIView *editView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    editView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.remindContentView addSubview:editView];
    WEAKSELF
    [editView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.equalTo(weakSelf.remindContentView).offset(kPadding);
        make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.remindContentView).offset(-kPadding);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(40);
    }];

    NSString *title = @"content:";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    CGFloat width = [title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT) attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }].width;
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.font = font;
    titleLabel.text = title;
    [editView addSubview:titleLabel];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.textField = textField;
    [self.textField setEnabled:YES];
//    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [editView addSubview:textField];

    [titleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(editView);
        make.centerY.equalTo(editView.mas_centerY);
        make.width.mas_equalTo(width);
    }];

    [textField mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(titleLabel.mas_right);
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(editView);
        make.centerY.equalTo(editView.mas_centerY);
        make.right.equalTo(editView);
    }];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView delegate
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (SignStepRemindCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    SignStepRemindCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[SignStepRemindCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [UITableViewCell cellHeightForIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView] + 10;
}


- (void)show:(UIView *)view
{
//    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIWindow *window = view.window;
//    self.window = window;
//    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
//    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//    window.alpha = 1;
//    window.hidden = NO;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];


    NSLog(@"key1-->%@, key2-->%@", [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow, window);

    UIView *backIv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.backIv = backIv;
    backIv.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    backIv.alpha = 0.7;

    [window addSubview:backIv];
    [window addSubview:self];

    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.7;

    [self mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.mas_equalTo(30);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(-30);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(screenHeight);
        make.center.equalTo(window);
    }];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];


    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)dismiss
{
    [self.backIv removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

#pragma mark - 滚动代理
#pragma mark scrollview减速完毕就会调用
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    //获取当前页码
    int pageNo = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    if (pageNo == 0) {
        [self.leftBtn setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.rightBtn setTitle:@"next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.titleLabel.text = @"select step";

        self.step = 0;
    } else {
        [self.leftBtn setTitle:@"pre" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.rightBtn setTitle:@"finish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.titleLabel.text = @"select person";

        self.step = 1;
    }
}


- (void)cancel
{
    if (self.step == 0) {//cancel
        [self dismiss];
    } else {//pre
        self.leftBtn.enabled = NO;
        self.rightBtn.enabled = NO;
        CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.x -= self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            self.scrollView.contentOffset = offset;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.rightBtn setTitle:@"next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            self.titleLabel.text = @"select step";

            self.step = 0;

            self.leftBtn.enabled = YES;
            self.rightBtn.enabled = YES;
        }];
    }
}


- (void)next
{
    if (self.step == 0) {//next
        self.leftBtn.enabled = NO;
        self.rightBtn.enabled = NO;
        CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.x += self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            self.scrollView.contentOffset = offset;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:@"pre" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.rightBtn setTitle:@"finish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            self.titleLabel.text = @"select person";

            self.step = 1;

            self.leftBtn.enabled = YES;
            self.rightBtn.enabled = YES;

        }];
    } else {//finish

    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
//    NSArray *subViews = [self.window subviews];
//    for (id obj in subViews) {
//        [obj removeFromSuperview];
//    }
//    [self.window resignKeyWindow];
//    [self.window removeFromSuperview];
//    self.window = nil;
}

@end
```

this is custom cell

```
#define kPadding 10
#import "SignStepRemindCell.h"

@interface SignStepRemindCell()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *unSelectedImage;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *selectedImage;
@end

@implementation SignStepRemindCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_icon_checkbox"];
        self.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_icon_checkbox_selected_all"];
        [self addViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addViews
{
    UIImageView *checkImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.selectedImage];
    [self.contentView addSubview:checkImageView];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    [self.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

    UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    subTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    subTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    subTitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    [self.contentView addSubview:subTitleLabel];

    WEAKSELF
    [checkImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView).offset(kPadding);
        make.centerY.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_centerY);
        make.size.mas_equalTo(weakSelf.selectedImage.size);
    }];

    [titleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView).offset(kPadding);
        make.left.equalTo(checkImageView.mas_right).offset(kPadding);
        make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView).offset(-kPadding);
        make.height.mas_greaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
    }];


    [subTitleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.mas_bottom).offset(5);
        make.left.equalTo(titleLabel.mas_left);
        make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView).offset(-kPadding);
        make.height.mas_greaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
    }];

    titleLabel.text = @"num：2";

    NSString *text = @"<strong>test：</strong>test1, test2, test3, test4";
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    subTitleLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
}

@end
```

I use this custom view in vc

```
SignStepRemindView *stepRemindView = [[SignStepRemindView alloc] init];
[stepRemindView show:self.view];
```

My question is the UITextField can't edit and touch,the keyboard has never been shown,but when I use [textField becomeFirstResponder],I can input,the keyboard show,but the cursor does not show.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.The reason is that constraints are not complete.
Add the following code at the end of the method addRemindView

```
[self.remindContentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
    make.bottom.equalTo(editView.mas_bottom).offset(20);
}];
```